# Manipulating users' computers remotely

Tags: remote, rdp

I need some service similar to Windows Terminal Services, which provides the ability to host multiple, simultaneous client sessions.

So, users run their applications on a remote server as if on their local computers. And I need a possibility to switch to their session and intercept their mouse and manipulate their computer remotely. Say, I'll have 10 users simultaneously.

Under Windows this is pretty natural via RDP (if I'm not mistaken), but I would like to migrate from Windows world.

Could you tell me whether this is possible under Ubuntu or some other Unix system? If yes, please, give me a link so that I could read some general information.

Comment: You can use desktop sharing or a VNC protocol. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers. FreeNx is a fast and secure option. - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX

Comment: The other answers here are fine if you need a GUI but if a GUI is not required then SSH is perfect.

Comment: Basically what you want to know is "what is the Ubuntu equivalent of RDP for interacting with the user's graphical desktops remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is just one of many solutions:

On your server, install a VNC server, like so:

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

Now you can start VNC sessions with the `vncserver` command. You can start as many as you like, or have your users SSH into your server and start the servers themselves.

Then use a VNC client on your client computers to connect to the server.